# covers another div with div height of 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying layout with css the div (dark blue) so that changes size according to the size of the window without covering the bottom panel, I thought that with the height to 100% official, but not understand because it ignores the panel below, and ends moving off the page

now that see not let me post pictures, so something is also what I have:

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="message">hi i'm a message</div><!--i can see this div-->
    <div id="darkBlue"></div>
    <div id="anotherPanel">you can't see me</div>
</div>
```

and this css

```
#container{//This container is attached to the right side
    right: 0;
    width: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
}
#darkBlue{//this div cover the next div
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background: #3a5193;
    bottom: 100px;
}
#anotherPanel{//i can't see this div.......
    height: 100px;
    botton: 0px;
}
```

Not sure if you can solve with css, or have to resort to using javascript (which is something I want to avoid), anyone knows some property who can help me?

UPDATE: This is the picture of what layout attempt: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t9nl5mb3sq85m3j/repro.png

Comment: make the position absolute.

Comment: There's a typo in the last definition line: `botton` instead of `bottom`.

Comment: sorry jeje, typo error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `bottom` `top` `left` `right` you must define `position`. In your case remove `bottom`  from `#darkBlue` `#anotherPanel` and add to  `#darkBlue` `height: calc(100% - 100px)`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6ymxq/)

**Update**

If you don't want to use  `calc` then add  `margin-bottom:-100px;` to `#darkBlue`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6ymxq/2/)

Comment: `calc` [may have unacceptable support consequences](http://caniuse.com/calc) and does not really degrade gracefully.

Comment: calc works, but I worry Niels's comment, what exactly are the consequences of using this method?

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a height of 100% to a child element it will take up 100% of the height of the parent element. If you want the element to cover the whole container without being in the document flow of the parent element you can try to do the following:

```
#darkBlue {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #3a5193;
}
```

**Edit:** @Niels has mentioned an additional detail I've not mentioned before. For this to work the parent elements position needs to be set to either `fixed`, `absolute` or `relative`

Comment: Don't forget that this only works if you properly assigned a positioning context to the parent by setting its `position` to `fixed`, `absolute` or `relative`.

Comment: His parent element in this case is set to `fixed`.

Comment: what I need is not covered by the other 2 div, but the extra space, it covers

Comment: @SargoDarya I know, I was adding it to the answer because it's vital for other readers to understand that the code in your answer doesn't work "standalone".

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the CSS of `anotherPanel`. You have `botton` instead of `bottom`. Also when using this CSS properties, is good to set the `position`.

Try this:

```
#anotherPanel{
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: #F00;
    position:absolute;
}
```

[Is this the droid you are looking for?](http://jsfiddle.net/Yr8TZ/)

Best.